# Dynamically loading Javascript and maintaining objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I am building an ajax based website, where almost every page has it's own Javascript file which is being loaded along with html.

I have couple questions if I'm doing things in a right way, so let's get started :)

First of all, the way I execute the loaded script. All of my code is encapsulated in a function, so say I have loaded the `register` page, what i would do is:

```
page_class = "register"; //this will change when new page is loaded
new window[page_class];
```

So this works the way I want it to work, but I'm concerned about one thing, when the user comes back from the other page to `register` one more time and new object are going to be created one more time will it create memory leaks or some other bad things? If so what can I do to `rerun` my whole script?

My next question is fairly simple, I attach my `jquery` events using `on` and when I switch the page I loop through **all** elements that will be removed and detach every element, is that enough to prevent memory leaks? If not what could i improve?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. First, you could make instantiation conditional so if the object already exists, don't duplicate. Secondly, what kind of "memory leaks" are you expecting? While I may not know your site's structure, I would say unless you're facebook or some other site where user's page view time is actually greater than the national average of like 1 minute then you have little to fear. Is you memory leak, in your opinion, limited to just duplicate objects?

Comment: @KaiQing: In a site that uses ajax-style loading for pages with `pushState`, memory leaks can become an issue because there is only ever one "page load". I am not sure how many websites are written like this, but many web applications must be concerned with memory leaks given this architecture.

Comment: Well you are right about object instantiation, and about memory leaks im not really sure what to expect that's why i made this question, it's my first project when content is fully ajax loaded. Yes it is going to be to facebook like website where user is going to stay for quite a while

Comment: @KaiQing You are going to want to leverage some frameworks to do this for you. You can use `socket.io`, `node.js`, and `angular.js` to combat memory leak issues.

Comment: Oh I know. I've had the torture of building many all ajax sites. I also have the torture of reviewing the analytics for these sites. Even on highly promoted sites the visit time is not long, or at least not long enough to matter. There are times when content can stack and become unstable. Like streaming music, videos, or anything else requiring a lot of visual feedback and resources. However, many sites are just basic content and conditionally preventing duplicate instantiation would be enough to avoid anything from crippling the performance of the browser.

Comment: @ohgodwhy - (nice name btw) that might be good but also may be overkill depending on the OP's needs. A sane plan for addressing js structure would be sufficient, but we don't know enough about his structure to make solid suggestions. I would assume a question like this leans more to standard html / js in normal deployment and nothing as sophisticated as node.

Comment: @KaiQing I was considering using `node.js` but since i'm completely inexperienced with i decided to go with just `ajax` calls and website is going to be pretty big, music streaming, video streaming, chat rooms, forums and many other things.

Comment: You don't have to loop through all elements and detach event handlers.  You can just use jQuery's `.empty()` or `.remove()` and it will take care of that kind of stuff for you.  As for the other questions about memory leaks, we'd have to see a lot more of your context to know.

Comment: @jfriend00 wow thank you i didn't know that those functions does that, that's awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So considering what we've figured out from the comments, here's my 2 cents:

I would suggest making your site sectionally ajaxed. By that I mean all music areas as one subsection, videos in another, etc. So within each section you ajax around and when transitioning to another section you gracefully fade and naturally page load the next.

`.detach()` in my opinion is not enough to ensure proper memory handling since detach keeps the removed section referenced. Good for when you want to recall it but useless if the user just clicked an area and backed out never to return. Now you have this reference to an entire section stored in memory.

How to handle memory in each section? You can maintain section objects. An example:

```
var music = {
    loaded: 0,
    current_track: null,
    init: function(){
        if(this.loaded == 0)
        {
            $.ajax... get your music section html and write it to the #music element
            this.loaded = 1;
        }
    },
    selectTrack: function(id)
    {
        // just an example
    }
};
```

while maintaining a constant site object:

```
var site = {
    init: function(){
        // call selected page, etc
    },
    move: function(page){
        if(page == 'music')
        {
            music.init();
            $('#content').animate(...);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    site.init();
});
```

Where the site obj is initted on page load and when the move function is called it calls the init method for the respective object, which does nothing if the page has already been loaded. This example obviously depends on there being a #music element as well as a container element called #content. This part could be totally irrelevant depending on how you handle transitions. All your call, but the general idea is the same. You can always set display to none to avoid rendering bottlenecks for complex markup.

You mentioned, at least briefly, that the project was expected to pretty big. Not to be too pessimistic, but "big" is defined after the fact and not in the plan. Unless you have millions of dollars to throw at this. I'm not trying to dissuade you. By all means, make your site as you expect it to be. But consider that scaling up when demand calls is a much more sane approach than going full throttle fancy before anyone knows about it.
I only say this because I've worked for clients who have thrown millions into the gig claiming it will be the next youtube and 6 months later they were gone. Where they focused on stability and security, they failed in design and marketing. That - and pretty much that alone - is why I suggest making only sections ajaxed. It keeps it compartmentalized, the focus is easy to keep track of and you only have that one piece to worry about. When you get 10,000 users, consider going full ajax. When you get there you may also know why it might be a better move to consider ipads and tablets over a fancy ajax site. Your cool transitions and fades will be a wounded dog on mobile devices. Considering the direction things are going, is that what you want?

Again, this is only my opinion. I don't know your site or skill set or even whether or not you have already considered all I mentioned. If you have any specific questions I can try to answer or update this post.
Good luck.

Regarding the js options mentioned:

Standard jquery will likely suffice, unless you have time to fully understand something like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html)

Node.js is awesome but you need to make sure your server can deploy it. Dreamhost, for example, does not support it. At least they didn't last I checked. They're a good example of a decent, common host. Same for Media Temple, I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You gave me some wonderful tips, and at current situation it seems that im doing things right, because with chrome `chrome://memory` help after monitoring memory usage when regularly browsing so far created pages memory stops increasing after all pages has been loaded.

And i have just one more question, as i been monitoring memory usage i have noticed that average page uses around ~2.5mb of data is that too much?

Comment: "Too much" is a term relative to the device calling your site. For a standard PC, no. Not in my opinion. But anywhere you can shave it down is a good idea. Most likely images will be the biggest culprits of large pages. Try loading your site on an iphone. See how long 2.5 megs takes and then ask yourself if it seemed unreasonable. Wifi, 3g, 4g, etc. Anything qualifies as a fair trial. If these things aren't at your disposal, you can try evaluating a similar site or a large one like ebay and see how they measure up.